Ubuntu login screen on startup instead of Kubuntu
Whenever I boot into Kubuntu 24.04 from GRUB it shows the Ubuntu login screen instead of the Kubuntu one. To clarify this, it only happens when booting up out of a shutdown or restart. Booting from sleep it gives me the correct KDE login screen.
A while ago I needed to reinstall the KDE desktop as it was being wonky and after that this happened. I was not able to find anything about why this happened. This is not an urgent matter as it still functions just fine its just a little annoying to be met with the Ubuntu login screen when I have Kubuntu installed. Changing my splash screen and SDDM screen has no effect on anything.
About this System:

Not my exact login screen but what comes up when booting:


That started  happening in my case  after using boot-repair,  but it happens only during boot (after selecting Kubuntu in my grub list), not at the login screen. The login screen should be 100% set by the SDDM theme.

Alright. I figured it out. After some research I discovered this article: Ubuntu stuck on login screen. After using the terminal to install lightdm it asked what bootloader I wanted to use as there were multiple of them. After selecting sddm the on boot login screen is back to normal. This might not work for everyone as it seems like a roundabout solution but it works.
